# Debugging MinimumBoundingGeometry_management() gives ERROR 000210?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, error-000210

I created a script to envolve points with polygons using the same value or ID. The main tool was the "Minimum Bounding Geometry", and so far my script is working good, but to convert to toolbox script It doesn't work good. I introduced the parameters but nothing happens, even do no errors show up. I verified the manual to convert the script to toolbox script but nothing solve this issues.

Someone can help me?

How I can convert correctly the script to toolbox or my script have a problem?

This is my script:

```
import arcpy, os, datetime

#Variables de entorno
Introduce_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Ruta_salida = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

arcpy.AddMessage('Introduce el shp de entrada:'+ Introduce_shp)
arcpy.AddMessage('Ruta de salida:'+ Ruta_salida)

Fecha = datetime.datetime.now()
dia = Fecha.day
mes = Fecha.month
year= Fecha.year
Nombre_archivo_shp = '{0}{1}{2}_Areas_almacenes_DICONSA.shp'.format(dia,mes,year)

#Une ruta y archivo
Ruta_salida_poligonos = os.path.join(Ruta_salida,Nombre_archivo_shp)

#Realiza proceso de areas
arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management(Introduce_shp, Ruta_salida_poligonos, "CONVEX_HULL", "LIST", "CVE_ALMACE", "NO_MBG_FIELDS")
```

However this gives an error.

Can somebody tell me how to solve the problem?

```
Running script Script1...

Introduce el shp de entrada:D:\SedesolVQB\Proyectos\proyecto_INFRASOCIAL\Capas_infraestructura_social\Capas de abril2017\n_loctdico_0417_09_.shp
Ruta de salida:D:\Documentos\ArcGIS\n_loctdico_0417_09__Script1.shp

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SedesolVQB\Proyectos\proyecto_MODELBUILDER_DGAAE\Areas_almacenes_v12.py", line 30, in <module>
    arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management(Introduce_shp, Ruta_salida_poligonos, "CONVEX_HULL", "LIST", "CVE_ALMACE", "NO_MBG_FIELDS")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 2576, in MinimumBoundingGeometry
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output D:\Documentos\ArcGIS\n_loctdico_0417_09__Script1.shp\1462017_Areas_almacenes_DICONSA.shp
Failed to execute (MinimumBoundingGeometry).
```

Comment: You need a comma between the two variables in os.path.join

Comment: thanks for your answer but continue the same issues, nothing happens

Comment: With Nombre_archivo_shp, if you're supplying a raw string with r' you don't need to double backslash, in fact if you're joining you don't supply a backslash at all :  Nombre_archivo_shp = str(dia)+str(mes)+str(year)+ '_Areas_almacenes_DICONSA.shp' then Archivo_salida = os.path.join(Guarda_el_shp_salida, Nombre_archivo_shp). What exception do you get when it fails?

Comment: Thansk for you help!!! I did what you said but nothing happens,no erros, notthing happens. I thing the problem is the join datetime with string'_Areas_almacenes_DICONSA.shp' and then the arguments in the arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management  --> Archivo_salida

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson *if you're supplying a raw string with `r` you don't need to double backslash* - While I agree that the backslash is not needed, you cannot end a raw python string with a single backslash, so `r'\'` would give a Parsing Syntaxerror

Comment: True @Midavalo. It's one of those funny python (and C) oddities that I had forgotten until you pointed it out. Good to see that at least *one* of us is fully awake.

Comment: Perhaps replace print 'Error en el proceso'+str(e) with arcpy.AddError('Error en el proceso'.format(e)) to get a persistent result that can be seen in the results tab. As for the joining datetime with string, use format: Nombre_archivo_shp = '{}{}{}_Areas_almacenes_DICONSA.shp'.format(dia,mes,year) it doesn't bunk out so easily, but arcpy.AddMessage(Nombre_archivo_shp) first to see if you're violating name restrictions for the shapefile. It would be best not to start the name with numbers and don't use any non alphanumeric characters except underscore.

Comment: The first thing that I think you should do is to remove the `try`/`except` statement so that you can see any error messages that Python is trying to provide.  In any event it sounds like your current script has changed since you posted your original code.  We need to see what the latest code and latest error message is.

Comment: Thank all you for your comments, It was very helpful!! I'm gonna changes my script and I'll see what happen.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot see what the tool user enters for the two parameters, so I think you need to `print` out their contents:

From the error at the end it looks like you have set:

```
Introduce_shp = 1462017_Areas_almacenes_DICONSA.shp
Ruta_salida = D:\Documentos\ArcGIS\n_loctdico_0417_09__Script1.shp
```

and that you have tried to concatenate a full path to a shapefile (including its name) with a shapefile name to make a pathname, instead of concatenating a workspace path and a file name.